# How to set up node data for Pathfinding algorithm in 2D platformer?

Tags: c++, algorithm, path-finding

I've been doing a lot of research into the A* pathfinding algorithm and I'm trying to incorporate it into my program. This is not a game that I created so I have no control over the frames. However, I am reading the necessary information from memory and think I can create coordinate based way points based on the game physics. Currently, I am grabbing all the platforms which are walkable and storing them inside their own doubly linked node based on if they are connected with their vertices. However, I am not sure where to go from here. What other information should I be storing inside of these nodes and how should I be connected one node list to another?

```
struct Platforms{
    LONG x1;
    LONG y1;
    LONG x2;
    LONG y2;
    struct Platforms *prev;
    struct Platforms *next;
};
std::vector<Platforms*>P;
void GetPlatforms(){
    int platformCount = (int)ReadPointer(CWvsPhysicalSpace2DBase,OFS_PlatformCount);
    LONG rightWall = ReadPointerSigned(CWvsPhysicalSpace2DBase, OFS_RightWall);
    LONG leftWall = ReadPointerSigned(CWvsPhysicalSpace2DBase, OFS_LeftWall);
    LONG downWall = ReadPointerSigned(CWvsPhysicalSpace2DBase, OFS_DownWall);
    LONG upWall = ReadPointerSigned(CWvsPhysicalSpace2DBase, OFS_UpWall);
    //add_log("Platform Count: %d", platformCount);
    for(int i=0; i<platformCount-1; i++){
        LONG x1, y1, x2, y2;
        x1 = GetValue(platStruct, OFS_PlatformLeft);
        y1 = GetValue(platStruct, OFS_PlatformTop);
        x2 = GetValue(platStruct, OFS_PlatformRight);
        y2 = GetValue(platStruct, OFS_PlatformBottom);
        if((x2)-(x1) > 0){ //Make sure the platform is traversable
            //add_log("\n\nPlatform: %d X1: %d Y1: %d X2: %d Y2: %d", i+1, x1, y1, x2, y2);
            if(P.size() > 0){
                bool newHead = true;
                for(std::vector<Platforms*>::size_type i = 0; i != P.size(); i++) {
                    Platforms *curr = P[i];
                    while(curr != NULL){
                        if(curr->x1 == x2 && curr->y1 == y2){//curr->y1 - y2 > -50 && curr->y1 - y2 < 50){ //To account for slope
                            insert_front(&curr, x1, x2, y1, y2);
                            newHead = false;
                            //add_log("front segment found: X1: %d Y1: %d X2: %d Y2: %d", curr->x1, curr->y1, curr->x2, curr->y2);
                            break;
                        } else if(curr->x2 == x1 && curr->y2 == y1){
                            insert_After(curr, x1, x2, y1, y2);
                            newHead = false;
                            //add_log("connected segment found: X1: %d Y1: %d X2: %d Y2: %d", curr->x1, curr->y1, curr->x2, curr->y2);
                            break;
                        }
                        curr = curr->next;
                    }
                }
                if(newHead == true){
                    struct Platforms* head = NULL;
                    insert_end(&head, x1, x2, y1, y2);
                    P.push_back(head);
                }
            }else{
                struct Platforms* head = NULL;
                insert_end(&head, x1, x2, y1, y2);
                P.push_back(head);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How far are you able to get with your A* implementation as you have it right now? Is there a specific example of a path that you want to be able to generate, that you cannot yet generate? Show us this path.

Comment: I am still working on creating the pathing graph so haven't implemented the A* yet. I'm stuck on how I should assign the costs to each node and how I can split the node based on jump/fall points. I pulled these variables from the game data ```float cGravity = -2000.0f;
float cMaxFallingSpeed = -670.0f;
float cWalkSpeed = 125.0f;
float cJumpSpeed = 455.0f; ``` so I am thinking that should create additional edges based on whether another node is reachable based on a jumping parabola

Comment: Let's keep things simple, and add complexity only as needed. So, let's start with all nodes at cost 1. If that later leads to the pathfinder choosing "bad" paths, you can change the costs later to discourage that behaviour. For the jump points, can you diagram for us the specific transitions you want to capture, and where you're stuck in expressing it? Then we can help you with those specific obstacles.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/uRn1flM). In the diagram, I have 3 seperate nodes links that represent platforms. The way I have it set up is that each node in the node link is walkable.  In the game physics, it allows you to jump up through a platform, or jump down through it. I am trying to figure out how to establish a connection/edge between those separate platform node links so that it becomes a node graph traversable by the algorithm. Do you think I should define another node in  my Platforms* structure to link to a jumpable platform and platforms that it can jump down from?